# Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Alan Turing?

Tags: england, geek-travel, science

I'm travelling to the UK from Australia and wanted to visit a number of sites of scientific history.

One at the top of my list is Alan Turing. (WWII Codebreaker and Pioneer of the Binary Computer Architecture).

There appears to be a [Computing History Museum](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/pages/13587/A-Museum-for-Cambridge/) at Cambridge.

There appears to be a [memorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing_Memorial) in Sackville Park, in Manchester.

There appears to be a [section](http://www.twickenham-museum.org.uk/detail.php?aid=66&ctid=1&cid=13) at the Twickenham Museum.

There appears to be a [display](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g187069-d1460366-r137468856-The_Manchester_Museum-Manchester_Greater_Manchester_England.html) at the Manchester Museum.

There is obviously the [display](https://www.bletchleypark.org.uk/) at Bletchley Park, and the [display](http://www.tnmoc.org/visit) at the National Museum of Computing.

There was also an [exhibition](http://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/visitmuseum/plan_your_visit/exhibitions/turing) at the London Science Museum - but this closed years ago.

There also appears to be the [Alan Turing Institute](https://www.turing.ac.uk/) at the British Library.

But can you visit a museum with a display about his life and works?

My question is: **Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Alan Turing?**

EDIT: Added note about London Museum display closing.

Comment: How many scientists/engineers are still on your list...?

Comment: There should be a "the answer is in the question" close reason...

Comment: @ThorstenS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_scientists

Comment: @JonathanReez He said "on *top* of *his list*" consecutively for [currently 7 scientists](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32269/hawkeye). I am curious how many questions more we may expect...

Comment: The exhibition at Science Museum closed on 20 October 2013. That's stated in bold above the rest of the description on the page you link to.

Comment: @fkraiem - stackoverflow generally requires you to do your research before you ask a question. Failure to do research is an actual reason for downvoting. I don't believe any of the links above provide a museum that is exclusively about Turing. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @hawkeye I think you've almost certainly got everything covered, but I'd shunt **Bletchley Park** up to the top of the list: in particular ["Block B"](https://www.bletchleypark.org.uk/visit-us/what-to-see/museum-in-block-b) which contains a gallery on the "Life and Works of Alan Turing" including things like his notebooks, and his old office (but obviously pretty much the whole place is relevant)

Comment: The Alan Turing Institute is not open to the public and there's nothing to see there, anyway: it's just a bunch of offices and meeting rooms. It also has no connection to Turing other than being named in his honour.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Actually, they're all described as "One at the top of my list". I don't think that's contradictory, assuming that it's a long list and the seven listed so far are close to the top.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers" (from the [help centre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

Comment: @fkraiem We can only have a limited number of pre-defined reasons and, honestly, I don't think this one comes up often enough to be worth losing another reason for. This is what custom close reasons are for.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You're trying close the question because it's well researched? If you know for a fact that the examples listed in the question are complete and accurate, then *that's the answer to the question*, and you should have some courage in your convictions and post it as an answer. I think the comment you're responding to was intended as a flippant joke, not a serious proposal ("..." is a clue).

Comment: @user568458 I'm directly quoting the help centre: that is a direct statement of site policy. If you disagree with the policy, take it up on Meta, but note that this policy appears in the help centre of (I believe) every Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your notes in the question pretty much cover it, but there's much more at **Bletchley Park** than just a display. There is:

- [In "Museum in Block B"](https://www.bletchleypark.org.uk/visit-us/what-to-see/museum-in-block-b), a whole gallery titled  **The Life and Works of Alan Turing**, including:

  - Copies of 15 of his 18 published mathematical papers. Here's a little about the [story of how they were saved by an online campaign](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-beds-bucks-herts-17256951)
  - Original notebooks containing some of his thoughts and mathematical forumulas
  - A modern statue of him
  - Information about his life and achievements outside of his work at Bletchley Park, and his impact, including:

    > ...a letter to Alan Turing's mother written 20 years after his death when she was told for the very first time what a huge contribution he'd made to the outcome of World War II and also the vital contribution he'd made to the modern computer
  - Various personal items donated by his family, including a teddy bear he used as a practice audience for his lectures, and a hand-drawn Monopoly board he played on as a child.
  - It's described as:

    > ...the most comprehensive exhibition of the life and works of Alan Turing in the world
- [In Hut 8](https://www.bletchleypark.org.uk/visit-us/what-to-see/hut-8):

  - > The real Office of Alan Turing, Head of Hut 8, recreated to how it would have looked in World War Two complete with the mug chained to the radiator.
  - Interactive displays about the work and methods of Turing and his team
- And of cause, almost all the other exhibits about the codebreaking work during the war are related to Turing, including:

  - > The only known example of used Banbury sheets, a system devised by Alan Turing to help find the daily-changing Enigma settings
  - > The world’s only fully operational Bombe rebuild – the electro-mechanical device used to mechanise the process of breaking Enigma
  - Recreations of what the codebreaking rooms were like during the war

Bletchley Park is definitely the place to start, and it'll also be worth talking to staff and volunteers who are likely to be able to tell you plenty more about him and about which other sites are worth seeing.

---

There's also a little about him in his **childhood home town of Guildford** in Surrey (a short distance south of London), which is [described in this article](http://www.exploringsurreyspast.org.uk/themes/people/scientists/alan_turing/). There's not much to see (an English Heritage Blue plaque outside his old family home, a road named after him...) but there is a [two mile guided walk](http://www.guildfordwalks.org.uk/walk2015AlanTuring.php) available with more of a focus on his childhood and how his family saw him.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't about Turing in particular, but you can see a replica of the [Manchester Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Small-Scale_Experimental_Machine), a computer that Turing programmed, and the first computer to store user-entered software in electronic memory, at [the Museum of Science and Industry, Manchester](http://msimanchester.org.uk/whats-on/show/meet-baby).

Answer (score 0):

In Cambridge MA USA, at the MIT Flea (electronics junk market), I saw a guy showing artifacts from an Engima machine.  Don't know if he has a more permanent exhibition or not.